# Paypal RETURN URL WITHOUT TOKEN?

Tags: paypal

Paypal Express Checkout -  how to set up the RETURN URL so it doesn't have TOKEN upon return. Example - in my settings I plainly instruct to return to mysite.com/usr/

Though Paypal (when user clicks "Return" link) adds token so the final return URL looks like this: mysite.com/usr/?token=EC-2DE87391GT0152110

Is there a way to get rid of `?token=EC-2DE87391GT0152110` ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get rid of that token. When customer returns to your website, the flow is not yet completed. You will need that token to perform next step ( GetExpressCheckoutDetails, DoExpressCheckoutPayments, etc ).

Unless the next API is called to complete the payment, the money will not move to your account.